# Unable to execute a C executable on java on windows 2012 R2 server

Tags: java, windows, windows-server-2012-r2

This could a java or a Windows 2012 R2 server bug. If you know of any such bug, please let me know or if possible provide an explanantion of this behaviour.

I have a C executable say abc.exe
The C executable can take several arguments like filesystems, cpuusage, diskactivity.

If executed as a standalone executable, I am able to get the correct outputs like below.

```
C:\>abc.exe filesystems

C:\|153590.18|42409.92

C:\>abc.exe cpuusage

0|66695468750|61397343750|2614375000|12005347187500
1|97592187500|67641250000|4430312500|11968204687500

C:\>abc.exe diskactivity

C:|4022841134000|130685650573674324|74051|1057397|20791424524|1131448|3579545|58083987000|7029363712|18017484800|6
```

But if I run the executable with the help of a java program as shown below, I am getting the correct outputs only for filesystems and cpuusage. But it returns no output for diskactivity.

for filesystems

```
C:\>java RuntimeCheck

C:\|153590.18|42409.92
```

Done.

for cpuusage

```
C:\>java RuntimeCheck

0|66695468750|61397343750|2614375000|12005347187500
1|97592187500|67641250000|4430312500|11968204687500
```

Done.

But for diskactivity

```
C:\>java RuntimeCheck
```

Done.

The java program is also given below.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class RuntimeCheck {
      public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
          String line;
          Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c C:\\nmupm.exe diskactivity");//have changed arguments as per requirements
          BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
          BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
          while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
          }
          bri.close();
          while ((line = bre.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
          }
          bre.close();
          p.waitFor();
          System.out.println("Done.");
        }
        catch (Exception err) {
          err.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
```

Basically, the java program is either not able to read from the standard out or something else is happening. This behaviour is only on Windows 2012 R2 server edition alone.

Can you please provide your suggestions on debugging this?

Thanks in Advance.